# HP LoadRunner (wlrun) exit with status 1

Tags: java, windows, logging, loadrunner

I am trying to run HP LoadRunner (wlrun.exe) command from Java Program and check the status at the exit of wlrun.exe command.

Sample Java Code:

```
 public class LRTest
 {
   private static int exitValue = -1;
   private class WlRunExecution extends Thread
   {
     Process p;
     String command = new String();

     public WlRunExecution(String command)
     {
       this.command = command;
     }

     public void run()
     {
       LRTest.exitValue = -1;
       try
       {
         this.p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(this.command);
         while (IsLoadRunnerRunning())
         {
           Thread.sleep(1000L);
         }
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
         System.out.println(e);
       }
     }

     public boolean IsLoadRunnerRunning()
     {
       boolean IsLoadRunnerRunning = false;
       try
       {
         LRTest.exitValue = this.p.exitValue();
       }
       catch (IllegalThreadStateException e)
       {
         IsLoadRunnerRunning = true;
       }
       return IsLoadRunnerRunning;
     }
    }

   public static void main(String[] arg)
   {
       LRTest test = new LRTest();
       test.runTest();
   }

   public void runTest()
   {
     WlRunExecution process = null;
     String command = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HP\\LoadRunner\\bin\\Wlrun.exe\"  -Run -TestPath  \"C:\\Test\\LoadRunner\\TestBing\\ScenarioBing.lrs\" -ResultName \"C:\\Test\\LoadRunner\\TestBing\\LRResult\"";
     //String command = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HP\\LoadRunner\\bin\\Wlrun.exe\"";
     try
     {
         process = new WlRunExecution(command);
         Thread t = new Thread(process);
         t.start();
         t.join();
         System.out.println("Process Exit code : " + exitValue);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage() + e);
     }
   }
 }
```

On running the program, **Process Exit Code is always 1** which means wlrun process is exited with some error. Even if I run "wlrun" without any argument and manually close the LoadRunner Controller after launch, still process exit code is 1. If I replace "wlrun.exe" with any other command (notepad,exe or AnalysisUI.exe or VuGen.exe) then Process Exit Code is 0.

On debugging, I observed following error in **Application Event Logs (Control Panel -> Administrator Tools -> Computer Management -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application)**. Everytime I run HP LoadRunner Controller, this warning is logged in application event log.

> HP.LT.Logger configuration failed creating context provider of the
>   type: HP.PC.Security.SSO.AppContextLoggingProvider, HP.PC.Security.SSO

Please help.

Comment: Have you contacted HP support for their feedback on whether this return code of '1' is an expected condition given your model of execution?

Comment: Yes, asked same question on HP Community forum as well. No response as of now.

Comment: As a moderator in multiple forums (but not here), be warned.  Cross posting the same question to multiple forums is heavily frowned upon.  It creates confusion as to which threads are reference for answers for people doing research, moderation cleanup challenges, etc...  On some forums this can result in a loss of an ability to post.   Please concentrate on one forum until you exhaust all options there.

Comment: Sure, will keep in mind in future.